# For two column article (ACM template), why does the newtheorem environment (definition) not span into one column?

Tags: theorems

I am trying to put a definition using the newtheorem environment for an ACM template. After it execution, it is not placed in the single column, rather it span towards the next column. I have attach the output. Please explain, why it is behaving abnormally? The MWE and the output (screen shot), is as follows.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\subsection{Mathematical Definitions}

\begin{dfn}[One-Way Hash Function]
Given $H(x)$, it is hard for any PPT bounded algorithm  $\mathcal{A}$ to find out $x$. The advantage $\epsilon$ of $\mathcal{A}$ in finding  another solution is defined as
$$\left\vert\Pr\left[
\left.\begin{array}{l}
x\in_R \{0,1\}^n\\y\leftarrow H(x)\\x'\leftarrow\mathcal{A}(y)
\end{array}
\right\vert H(x')=y\right] \right \vert\geq\epsilon$$
\end{dfn}
\begin{dfn}[Negligible Function with K tretitors in IBE scheme]
content...
\end{dfn}
```

[image]

Comment: please don't just post an image of code it is really hard to debug. Make a small self contained document that shows the problem and add it as a code section to your question. Presumably the definition of `defn` that you have not shown always typesets the title on one line but hard to say why or how to change it just from a picture of the output.

Comment: it looks like the theorem title is set in a box.  (this can be seen by the uniform spacing in the header of the first line, "definition 3".)  more information is needed, in particular the document class and theorem package, preferably embedded in a small example that will compile showing the problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, David Carlisle... The MWE  and the output screenshot is attached. Please share your views for the Definition 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sig-alternate` setup of theorem-like environments typesets the whole label, including the attribution/name part, in a box.

This does not happen when `amsthm` is loaded. However, in order to allow using `amsthm` one has to remove the definition of `proof` and reinstate it afterwards.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}

\let\sigproof\proof\let\proof\relax
\let\sigendproof\endproof\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage{amsthm}

\let\proof\sigproof
\let\endproof\sigendproof

\newtheoremstyle{sig}
  {}
  {}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\scshape}
  {.}
  {.5em}
  {#1 #2\thmnote{\quad(#3)}}

\theoremstyle{sig}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Mathematical Definitions}

\begin{dfn}[One-Way Hash Function]
Given $H(x)$, it is hard for any PPT bounded algorithm  $\mathcal{A}$ 
to find out $x$. The advantage $\epsilon$ of $\mathcal{A}$ in finding 
another solution is defined as
\[
\left\vert
\Pr\left[
\begin{array}{l}
x\in_R \{0,1\}^n\\y\leftarrow H(x)\\x'\leftarrow\mathcal{A}(y)
\end{array}
\middle\vert\; H(x')=y\right] \right\vert\geq\epsilon
\]
\end{dfn}

\begin{dfn}[Negligible Function with K tretitors in IBE scheme]
content...
\end{dfn}

\end{document}
```

I see no way for allowing long theorem names within the standard code of `sig-alternate`.

[image]

Comment: Thank You. But when i compile, it throws the following error... Command \proof already defined. @egreg

Comment: @SibaMishra Now it should work