# ACM sig-alternate document class -- How to create unnumbered theorem-like environments

Tags: numbering, acm, newtheorem

The command `\newtheorem` in the ACM `sig-alternate` document class takes two arguments. The first is the name of the environment and the second is the header, rendered in small-caps letters, that appears at the start of each occurrence of the construct.

Example MWE:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
\newtheorem{IP}{Interpretation Problem}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\begin{document}

% Copyright
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}


% DOI
\doi{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN
\isbn{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

%Conference
\conferenceinfo{PLDI '13}{June 16--19, 2013, Seattle, WA, USA}

\acmPrice{\$15.00}


\conferenceinfo{WOODSTOCK}{'97 El Paso, Texas USA}
\title{ABC}
\numberofauthors{2}
\author{
\alignauthor
ABC\\
\affaddr{Department of Computer Science and Engineering}
% 2nd. author
\alignauthor
XYZ\\
\affaddr{Department of Computer Science and Engineering}\\
}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract} Here is the abstract. 
\end{abstract}
\section{Intro}
This is the first section.
\begin{IP}
Given a set of services $S$ consisting $o$ operations, identify the subset of faulty operations...
\end{IP}
\begin{axiom}
contents...
\end{axiom}
\end{document}
```

By this, its appropriate number is appended and the text is set in italics.

I want to remove the numbering from this environment. How to do that?

Moreover, IEEE supports this. If we use

> \newtheorem*{axiom*}{Axiom}

It would meet the need. However, the same is not working in ACM SIG template. Please suggest how to fix this issue.

The snapshot is attached for your reference. Have a look. How to remove the numbering from the newtheorem style environment.

[image]

Comment: I believe you know the drill: Don't just provide code snippets; instead, provide a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001). Please don't make would-be providers of answers guess pointlessly which document class needs to be loaded to replicate the issue(s) you're experiencing.

Comment: @Mico. Now it has been taken care.

Comment: It seems that only 8 percent (just a guess) of your picture are actually relevant. Can you crop the image please?

Comment: Your MWE isn't compilable because the `axiom` environment isn't defined. Also, the `\author{...}` and `\end{document}` statements are missing.

Comment: @Mico, Johannes_B. Earlier it was a mistake. Now it is taken care completely.

Comment: @egreg -- i took a look at the code in the class file.  too many names are the same in `amsthm`, and i suspect that some "already defined" conditions would reach out and bite.

Answer (score 3):

Old ACM styles are old.  Really old: they predate TeX3.  One of their quirks is that they follow old LaTeX standards.  Those did not allow unnumbered theorems (see Lamport's book).  Another quirk is that they redefine some LaTeX constructions in many incompatible ways, so the use of packages became a risky business.

To make the long story short:

1. Mico's advice above works, but it might break in an unexpected place, so be careful.
2. I am happy to report that the new spiffy style `acmart` is released and going to become the official ACM style "really soon".  I hope it will make authors' lives easier.

Comment: Good news indeed that the `acmart` document class is available (thanks to you, of course!) and that it's poised to become the new standard.

Comment: What should be the replacement for `sig-alternate-05-2015`?

Comment: The `sigconf` options to the `acmart` class will replace `sig-alternate` and its clones.  There are `siggraph`, `sigchi` and other options for different conferences

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you add the following instructions *before* `\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}`:

```
\RequirePackage{ntheorem}
\theoremheaderfont{\mdseries\scshape\hspace{\parindent}}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorempreskip{1\baselineskip}
```

These instructions (a) load the `ntheorem` package and (b) make the appearance of theorem-like environments conform to what's provided by the `sig-alternate-05-2015` document class.

Then, after the `\documentclass` instruction, you may write

```
\newtheorem*{IP}{Interpretation Problem}
\newtheorem*{axiom}{Axiom}
```

These instructions set up two unnumbered theorem-like environments.

---

A full MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{ntheorem}
\theoremheaderfont{\mdseries\scshape\hspace{\parindent}}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorempreskip{1\baselineskip}
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
\newtheorem*{IP}{Interpretation Problem}
\newtheorem*{axiom}{Axiom}
\begin{document}

% Copyright
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
% DOI
\doi{10.475/123_4}
% ISBN
\isbn{123-4567-24-567/08/06}
%Conference
\conferenceinfo{PLDI '13}{June 16--19, 2013, Seattle, WA, USA}
\acmPrice{\$15.00}
\conferenceinfo{WOODSTOCK}{'97 El Paso, Texas USA}
\title{ABC}
\author{DEF}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract} 
Here is the abstract. 
\end{abstract}

\section{Intro}
This is the introduction.
\begin{IP}
Given a set of services $S$ consisting $o$ operations, identify the subset of \dots
\end{IP}

\begin{axiom}
Contents \dots
\end{axiom}

More text following the axiom \dots
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use `amsthm`, provided you fix the `proof` environment, with a variation of `http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303810/4427` (my answer to another question of yours):

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}

\let\sigproof\proof\let\proof\relax
\let\sigendproof\endproof\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage{amsthm}

\let\proof\sigproof
\let\endproof\sigendproof

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{sig}
  {}
  {}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\scshape}
  {.}
  {.5em}
  {#1\@ifnotempty{#2}{ #2}\thmnote{\quad(#3)}}% <--- changed!
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{sig}

\newtheorem{IP}{Interpretation Problem}
\newtheorem*{axiom*}{Axiom}

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
This is the first section.
\begin{IP}
Given a set of services $S$ consisting $o$ operations, 
identify the subset of faulty operations...
\end{IP}
\begin{axiom*}
contents...
\end{axiom*}
\end{document}
```

[image]